# Saving data objects between sessions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, object, persistence

I'm putting the last bit of functionality in my application.  One of the things I want to do s have the user be able to save notes.  Each note has a title and a body that the user specifies.  When the user hits save, I want the title and body to be saved in an object, and have that object added to an array (which will later be used to populate a tableview).  What is the best way to save this array of data objects between sessions?

Comment: possible repost of [List of objects to be saved between sessions iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253865/list-of-objects-to-be-saved-between-sessions-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Core Data to do this. Create a "Note" object with the fields you want. Read up on Core Data programming because it is a whole subject, but in essence you will end up with an underlying sqlite data store that you will interact with using NSManagedObjects

Comment: okay.  on a related note, would I need to read up on the same thing if I wanted to take rows from an existing sqlite file and create new tables which will save between sessions?

Comment: If you want to use Core Data(which I'm sure you do), then yes. Do you mean that a released version of your app is already using plain sqlite? If so, then you can write some migration code to read all of its data and then write it to Core Data.

Comment: I haven't released the application, but is there a way to use Core Data after I've already started the application?  I've already done a lot and would hate to have to start over.

Comment: There is, like I said. In general though you will be much happier if you just cut your losses and switch to Core Data. This is particularly true for an app that's not even released yet because doing the migrations will cause you headache later. Of course, if you are not storing a lot of data and don't mind working with sqlite directly, you can just keep going with that.